# No Items on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo

Whenever I enter Google Play Store on my phone, there are almost no apps available for me to download except for a very few (like 1 or 2) that are featured as the 'most popular.' On most categories, though, the screen is empty and an error message appears with a "Retry" button.

...Of course, the "Retry" button doesn't work and my Play Store remains empty.

I have a working Internet connection so I don't understand what's going on here. Apps installed prior to this issue works just fine, though.

My phone is not rooted, and I'm using Samsung Galaxy U running on Android Froyo 2.2.1.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Would the lack of TLS 1.2 support explain why I couldn't connect any accounts with two-factor authentication with my phone (adding from Settings --> Accounts and Sync)?

Comment: @Robert I think you should put the answers from your comments as a proper answer as they are relevant, and could be for others.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is very very old. I am not sure if Google Play Store is still supported on Android 2.2 - if it would be still supported it would be the oldest

The current Android development tools can't create apps for Android 2.2 anymore, hence it is impossible to support such old apps. Also there are no emulators or devices available for testing apps on such an old platform. I assume for these reasons most developers have removed their apps with Froyo support from Play Store.

Additionally Froyo totally lacks support for TLS 1.2, hence it is now next to useless for Internet services as most web servers require TLS 1.2 or higher. There is a special [Google Crypto Provider](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider) included in Google Services, however I am not sure if this provider is really available on Android 2.2 and additionally it is only used by apps which explicitly make use of it.